# LVM: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00

Tags: redhat, lvm, rhel5, diskmanagement, udev

I'm on a server that shows a duplicate VG name. How can I rename one of these VolGroups to get rid of this conflict?

```
[root@dev-server dev]# lvs
  WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
  WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: Existing zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
  LV       VG         Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  LogVol00 VolGroup00 -wi-ao  30.00G
  LogVol01 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 127.91G
  backup   VolGroup00 -wi-ao 300.00G
  rman     VolGroup00 -wi-ao 300.00G
[root@dev-server dev]# pvs
  WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
  WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: Existing zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
  WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: Existing zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
  PV                  VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/cciss/c0d0p2   VolGroup00 lvm2 a--    1.64T 918.62G
  /dev/cciss/c0d1p1   VolGroup00 lvm2 a--    3.27T   3.27T
  /dev/mpath/mpath0p2 VolGroup00 lvm2 a--  405.88G      0

 vgdisplay
  WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
  WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: Existing zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
  WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: Existing zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup00
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               405.88 GB
  PE Size               32.00 MB
  Total PE              12988
  Alloc PE / Size       12988 / 405.88 GB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup00
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               4
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               4.91 TB
  PE Size               32.00 MB
  Total PE              160955
  Alloc PE / Size       24253 / 757.91 GB
  Free  PE / Size       136702 / 4.17 TB
  VG UUID               zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87
```

My quick attempt to re-name the VolGroup (could be doing this wrong...):

```
[root@dev-server dev]# vgrename /dev/cciss/c0d1 /dev/VolGroup02
      WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
      WARNING: Duplicate VG name VolGroup00: Existing zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 (created here) takes precedence over ifDUDd-ePmZ-Er7H-xwst-70dY-hB3M-6YDNZc
      Volume group name cciss/c0d1 has invalid characters
    [root@dev-server dev]#
```

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                       30G   17G   12G  59% / /dev/cciss/c0d0p1      99M   30M   65M  32% /boot tmpfs                  63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-rman
                      296G  8.9G  272G   4% /rman/11g /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-backup
                      296G   34G  248G  12% /backup
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the man page:-

```
"vgrename Zvlifi-Ep3t-e0Ng-U42h-o0ye-KHu1-nl7Ns4 VolGroup00_tmp"
   changes  the name of the Volume Group with UUID Zvlifi-Ep3t-e0Ng-U42h-o0ye-KHu1-nl7Ns4 to "VolGroup00_tmp".
```

...so for your case:-

```
vgrename zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87 newvolgroupname
```

...will rename the volume group with ID **zOuHvA-QTBR-wNPs-3GIQ-b2zQ-yOeH-2fBS87** to **newvolgroupname**.

Comment: Only the existing volume group can be renamed if a second conflicts though.

Comment: What typically causes this issue?

Answer (score 2):

> Name
>
> vgrename - rename a volume group Synopsis
>
> vgrename [-A|--autobackup {y|n}] [-d|--debug] [-h|-?|--help]
>   [-t|--test] [-v|--verbose] OldVolumeGroup{Path|Name|UUID}
>   NewVolumeGroup{Path|Name} Description
>
> vgrename renames an existing (see vgcreate(8)) volume group from
>   OldVolumeGroup{Name|Path|UUID} to NewVolumeGroup{Name|Path}. All the
>   Volume Groups visible to a system need to have different names.
>   Otherwise many LVM2 commands will refuse to run or give warning
>   messages.
>
> This situation could arise when disks are moved between machines. If a
>   disk is connected and it contains a Volume Group with the same name as
>   the Volume Group containing your root filesystem the machine might not
>   even boot correctly. However, the two Volume Groups should have
>   different UUIDs (unless the disk was cloned) so you can rename one of
>   the conflicting Volume Groups with vgrename.
>
> Options
>
> See lvm(8) for common options. Examples
>
> Renames existing volume group vg02 to my_volume_group: vgrename
>   /dev/vg02 /dev/my_volume_group
>
> or
>
> vgrename
>
> vg02 my_volume_group
>
> Changes the name of the Volume Group with UUID
>   Zvlifi-Ep3t-e0Ng-U42h-o0ye-KHu1-nl7Ns4 to VolGroup00_tmp:
>
> vgrename Zvlifi-Ep3t-e0Ng-U42h-o0ye-KHu1-nl7Ns4
>
> VolGroup00_tmp

Link: http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgrename

... as for

> ```
>   Volume group name cciss/c0d1 has invalid characters
> ```

`/dev/cciss/c0d1` is not a VG, so you cannot rename it. This is a PV on which a VG is probably based.